# how to get a data from a url and redirect based on the content

Tags: url, redirect, html, fetch

HI..
i want to know how to fetch or get a data from a url  (for ex : in the following url  http://abc.xyz.com i need to fetch only xyz and have to redirect to that xyz web page) and have to redirect it to the web page based on the content which i fetched.

thank u

Answer (score 0):

Providing you're using PHP:

- To fetch data from a URL use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).
- To redirect use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Ask a broad question, get a broad answer. The links will tell you everything you need to know.